# Как правильно  по-русски "Белоруссия" или "Беларусь"?

Tags: нормы-языка

Как правильно  по-русски "Белоруссия" или "Беларусь"? 
И почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта правильны. Официальное название государства - Республика Беларусь.

Подробно: [Беларусь или Белоруссия? | news.tut.by](http://news.tut.by/society/84891.html)

Допишу здесь: в комментариях нельзя давать скрытые ссылки. О Беларуси — всего лишь мнение Артемия Лебедева, не являющегося лингвистом. Куда более авторитетный Солженицын не признавал приставку "бес". Что с того?

Comment: Артемий Лебедев, § 121. Об употреблении некоторых топонимов, 20 ноября 2005 

>По-русски правильно писать Таллин (а не Таллинн), Алма-Ата (а не Алматы), Белоруссия (Беларусь — это трактор), поехать на Украину (а не в Украину), независимо от того, что думают по этому поводу жители указанных мест.

Взято отсюда: [Об употреблении некоторых топонимов](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/121/).

Как быть?

Comment: "Быть" тут не надо. В другой раз Артемия Великого можете смело послать, он не филолог. Но тут он по существу прав не только с Белоруссией, но и с остальными случаями (кроме Украины, где он тоже почти прав, но есть что обсудить).

Comment: Соглашусь, кстати, с Лебедевым. Именно по той причине, что в каждой стране свои традиции относительно наименования топонимов. И, заметьте, что ту же Финляндию никто в России не называется Суоми. Хотя для обеспечения всемирной справедливости стоило бы. :-)

Answer (score 4):

По-русски правильно Белоруссия или Бел**о**русь, такое название встречается в текстах, написанных не только до 1991, но и до 1917 г.
А вот Беларусь - это уже по-новорусски. От времени, когда политика затуманила голову не только политикам, но и филологам.

> У нас есть подобная проблема с названием Татарстан. Ревнители русского
>   языка говорят, что надо писать Татария. А вот мне это мнение не
>   нравится. Просто я видела, как разгоралась межнациональная рознь (в
>   80-ые, 90-ые), с какими бешеными глазами митинговали на площади
>   Свободы татарские националисты.

С Татарией/Татарстаном - и вообще со станами - все иначе. 
Хотя прежде всего. Крики любых националистов мне одинаково противны, хоть русских, хоть татарских, хоть папуасских. Но это никак не должно - в идеале - влиять на сугубо топонимический вопрос, касающийся к тому же только русского языка.

//===========

Так вот, я исхожу из того, что общеиндоевропейское "-стан" сохранилось в русском языке (или заново образовалось - тут не принципиально) и воспринимается как вполне "родное". 
Таким образом топонимические образования со "-стан" не только не чужды русскому языку, но и вполне продуктивны. Иногда они идут параллельно с образованиями на -ия (Турменистан-Туркмения), иногда разделяются с последними по значению (Индия-Индостан), бывает, что существует только один вариант, второй невозможен фонетически или исторически (Чувашия, Киргизия: Кыргызстан - это дикость для русского уха; Туркестан, Пакистан и проч.), чаще всего возможны оба варианта, но один из них активно вытесняет другой, однако не убивает последний оканчательно.

В случае с Татарстаном мы имеем как раз последний случай. "Татария" было основным вариантом на протяжении многих веков, но "Татарстана" никто не отменял. Поэтому этот "старый новый" вариант легко воспринялся русским языком (в отличие от, скажем, Башкортостана или того же Кыргызстана). В таком случае я не вижу причин препятствовать использованию "национального" произношения или словообразования. Хотя, как сказал, неприятно само использование этого факта в каких-то националистических играх.

//--------

Перечитал тут мнение vvermin, который сам себя, похоже, убедил своими пространными  доводами про транслитерацию Кот-Д'ивуар, но более - никого.
Там элементарная подмена прошла. Сначала декларируется, что "Беларусь" - транслитерация, а потом уже на этот тезис накручивается все что угодно.

Все не так. Беларусь - это заимствование. навязанное, ненужное русскому, но именно заимствование. А законы заимствования не обязаны следовать законам ни транслитерации, ни транскрипции, ни вообще каким либо законам, кроме собственных (по большей части - статистических, частотных) закономерностей.

Почему это именно заимствование? Да уже потому, что по мнению авторов этого новояза 90-х возникло новое понятие (иначе бы и разговору об отказе от Беларуси не было). И вместе с понятием пришло, позаимствовано новое слово, его обозначающее (опять - же по версии апологетов этого уродца). 
Теперь читаем, что такое траслитерация. ***"Передача знаков одной письменности знаками другой".*** Так вот, если даже считать белорусскую и русскую письменность разными (а это в данном контексте вполне уместно; иначе опять бы встал о самом существовании этого образования), то ***русский знак О*** как раз и передаёт орфографически белорусский орфографический знак А. 
Фонетика тут как раз одинакова.
Так что именно с точки зрения транслитерации написание "Белорусь" никак не менее уместно, чем "Беларусь". Так что апологетам "Беларуси" следует давить как раз на заимствование, а не на транслитерацию, иначе у них аргументов совсем не остаётся, одни крики.

Но в чем проблема. Признавая Беларусь заимствованием, а не орфографическим вариантом, мы вынуждено сталкиваемся с "беларусами", да не простыми, а "беларускими"... Которым очень трудно объяснить, что такая ползучая аннексия русской орфографии не может продолжаться вечно. Ведь в последнем случае "беларуский" это уже не корень новоявленного русского слова, это уже посягательство на суффикс. А дальше, как верно сказано, нам придется писать на  "бялорускам наречыи великава и магучева рускава языка".

Comment: Ну, Индостаном называют территорию в общем, когда Индия - страна, расположенная на этой территории, но не полностью еe занимающая. Из википедии: "Индостан - полуостров на юге Азии. На территории Индостана находятся государства Индия, Бангладеш и Пакистан."

Comment: Я ж и говорю, это пример того, как значения разделяются. Добавил: "по смыслу". Так понятнее?

Answer (score 1):

Господа, вы неправы. Верховный Совет БССР 19 сентября 1991 года принял «Закон Белорусской Советской Социалистической Республики о названии Белорусской Советской Социалистической Республики». В этом Законе еще до распада СССР наша БССР была переименована в Республику Беларусь (мой перевод на русский):

«Белорусскую Советскую Социалистическую Республику далее называть «Республика Беларусь», а в укороченных и составных названиях – «Беларусь».

И обращаю внимание на продолжение текста этого Закона:

«Установить, что эти названия транслитеруются на другие языки в соответствии с беларуским звучанием».

Транслитерация (Transliteration) - перевод одной графической системы алфавита в другую, то есть передача букв одной письменности буквами другой. Что означает, например, для русского языка, что в нем нет больше никакой «Белоруссии», а обязана быть только и именно одна «Беларусь».

Сегодня во всех официальных международных мероприятиях (саммиты СНГ, спортивные соревнования, торговые соглашения и пр.) это строго соблюдается: есть только название «Беларусь». В паспортах и прочих документах РБ на русском языке – тоже только «Беларусь», никакой «Белоруссии».

Общероссийский классификатор стран мира OK (MK (ИСО 3166) 004—97) 025-2001 (ОКСМ) (принят и введен в действие постановлением Госстандарта РФ от 14 декабря 2001 г. № 529-ст) тоже категоричен: он предусматривает только формы «Республика Беларусь» и «Беларусь», а какая-то фантастическая «Белоруссия» им не предусмотрена – такой страны не существует.

Главным в Законе о названии страны является пункт о ТРАНСЛИТЕРАЦИИ ее названия на другие языки мира (включая русский). Дело в том, что некоторые страны такого пункта не имеют и потому могут по-разному называться в разных языках: например, в русском нет никакой Норге, а есть Норвегия, вместо Данмарк – Дания, Суоми – Финляндия, Дойчланд – Германия, вместо Летува – Литва. Ни Финляндия, ни Германия, ни Летува не заявляли о том, что их самоназвания Суоми, Дойчланд и Летува транслитеруются на другие языки – и не просили другие страны их отныне называть именно так. А вот Беларусь именно это заявила в своем Законе. И точно так в свое время Персия попросила называть её Ираном, Цейлон – Шри-Ланкой, Берег Слоновой Кости – Кот д' Ивуаром, Бирма – Мьянмой, Северная Родезия – Замбией, Бенгалия – Бангладеш, Верхняя Вольта – Буркина Фасо. Именно под новыми названиями эти страны известны сегодня во всем мире, в том числе в РФ.

Если бы противники термина «Беларусь» в русском языке показали нам, что Россия пренебрегает этими правилами и продолжает называть Иран Персией, а Шри-Ланку Цейлоном – то в таком случае их мнение имело бы какую-то аргументацию. А в данном случае такая избирательность непонятна: чем же мы хуже Ирана или Шри-Ланки, если в России СМИ и просто россияне не желают признавать наше новое название и упрямо именуют старым несуществующим «Белоруссия»?

Тем не менее термин «Беларусь» все-таки СТАЛ ЯЗЫКОВОЙ РЕАЛИЕЙ русского языка, так как активно используется в ООН (где один из языков – русский) и всем государственным аппаратом РФ: всеми министерствами.

Таким образом, слово «Беларусь» стало частью русской лексики. Причем – используется не столько в быту, сколько в официозе, а это означает тенденцию вытеснения со временем старого слова «Белоруссия» и в разговорном русском. Пишется слово именно через «а», как этого и требует наш Закон о транслитерации названия страны – нигде в официальных документах РФ не используется слово «Белорусь» - ЕГО ПРОСТО НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ в русском языке.

В спорах со мной на эту тему многие российские «тугодумы» соглашались, что слово «Беларусь» стало частью русского языка из-за его использования российским официозом, но все равно упорствовали: мол, это слово «неправильное», а правильно – делать русскую соединительную «о».

Но если слово только ТРАНСЛИТИРУЕТСЯ на русский язык – то о каких же «нормах русского языка» можно говорить? Вот прямая аналогия: французское Кот д' Ивуар. Почему же никто равно не возмущается и не говорит, что по-русски правильно писать по-старому «Берег Слоновой Кости»? Или беларуский язык – это не такой же иностранный язык, как французский? Или Беларусь – это не суверенное государство, как Кот д' Ивуар, а часть РФ?

Коль «Беларусь» - языковая реалия русского языка, то как по правилам русского языка должно образовываться название гражданина Беларуси? Правильно: белАрус.

Здесь возражения о соединительной «о» вообще неуместны, так как изначальное слово «Беларусь» образовано не по правилам русского языка. А на этот счет в русском языке свои нормы: корнем слова является в таком случае все слово «Беларусь» (а не два тут корня).

Вместо того чтобы воспринимать слово «Беларусь» как ЗАИМСТВОВАННОЕ из другого языка, россияне по инерции его делят на два корня – что противоречит правилам русского языка о заимствованных словах.

Следуя этому правилу, и в русском языке равно транслитерации подлежит не только слово «Беларусь», но и производные понятия народа этой страны и ее языка – как политическое значение, НЕОТДЕЛИМОЕ от названия страны. Они РАВНО ТРАНСЛИТИРУЮТСЯ в рамках транслитерации названия страны «Беларусь». Таким образом, автоматически подлежат транслитерации слова «беларус» и «беларуский язык».

Это тоже строго в рамках правил русского языка. Равно как слово «Беларусь» является заимствованным транслитерацией в русском языке и не подлежит делению на два корня – точно так заимствованное слово «беларуский» является КОРНЕМ до буквы «к» (согласно правилам русского языка, заимствованные слова являются корнями до своих окончаний).

И, как заимствованное слово русского языка, не подлежит аналогично ни делению на два корня, ни правилу русского языка по удвоению «с» между «с» в корне и суффиксом. Так как этого правила нет в исходом для транслитерации беларуском языке – а транслитерация, напомню, сохраняет нормы грамматики исходного языка СВОЕЙ СТРАНЫ. А главное: само слово «беларуский» - заимствованное, и в нем русский язык не имеет права вычленять суффиксы.

Что касается окончаний (автор статьи в журнале «Родина» утрировал: «ну нет, тогда уж «беларускава»), то вот как раз в этом вопросе, согласно нормам русского языка, должны уже соблюдаться нормы русского языка. Заимствованные в русский язык слова сохраняют свои иностранные корни, но имеют падежные формы уже по русским правилам. Так что и тут «мимо»...

Comment: Белая  Русь,  Белоруссия  -  край,  область  Российской  империи,  как  же  ей  и  называтся,  если  не  на  русском  языке.  А  Беларусь  это  суверенное  государство,  с  суверенным  своим  языком,  которое  требует  такого  произношения  официально.  Так  в  чём  проблема ?  Это  молодое  государство.  У  него  нет  исторически  сложившихся,  традиционных  наименований  в  других  языках.  При  чем  здесь  по-русски  или  по-белорусски ?  Сама  Беларусь  так  хочет,  значит  так  надо  говорить.  Но  на  слова  белорус,  белорусский  язык  я  бы  эти  правила  не  распространял.

Comment: Потому,  что  это  не  новые  реалии  ни  вообще,  ни  для  русского  языка.

Comment: @wermin, я Вам ответил в тексте своего ответа. Извините, что c опозданием на полтора года. Только сейчас обратил внимание на Ваше послание.

Answer (score 0):

Названия стран мира можно найти:
а) в общероссийском классификаторе стран мира ([википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0))
б) на политической карте мира ([Google maps](https://www.google.by/maps/place/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C/@53.7169415,27.9775789,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x46da2584e2ad4881:0xa1d181ec8c10!8m2!3d53.709807!4d27.953389?hl=ru), [Яндекс карты](https://yandex.by/maps/149/belarus/?ll=27.977427%2C53.788970&mode=search&sll=27.701393%2C52.858248&source=wizgeo&text=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C&utm_medium=maps-desktop&utm_source=serp&z=7), [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C#map=6/53.305/28.960))

в) в перечне стран-участниц ООН ([оф. сайт ООН](https://www.un.org/ru/member-states/))

Беларусь — правильное название страны.

Comment: Видите ли в чем дело... Есть кодифицированные названия (которые в справочеиках) и есть *правильные*  с точки зрения языка, а не политиков. А в целом ответ ваш нуждается в большей аргументации. Карта аргументом точно не является, а на классификатор надо бы ссылку дать (хотя я знаю, что там именно так, но таковы правила ресурса).

Comment: @дармаед Приветствую Вас на сайте. Зря Вы изничтожили поставленные мною знаки препинания. Ваше сообщение оформлено в виде перечня,  поэтому в конце каждой строки необходима точка с запятой, а в конце самой последней — точка.

Comment: *Беларусь — правильное название страны* Следует ли из вашего утверждения, что Белоруссия - название неправильное? И если да, то почему?