# "На Украину" или "в Украину"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, топонимика

Как правильно: поехать *на* или *в* Украину?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Литературная норма современного русского языка: на Украине, на Украину, с Украины. Но, как сказал Н. Сванидзе в своем ток-шоу: «Грамматически правильно *на Украине*, но политически правильно *в Украине*». Так что без политики обойтись не получится.

«В 1993 году по требованию Правительства Украины нормативными следовало признать варианты *в Украину* (и соответственно *из Украины*). Тем самым, по мнению Правительства Украины, разрывалась не устраивающая его этимологическая связь конструкций *на Украину* и *на окраину*. Украина как бы получала лингвистическое подтверждение своего статуса суверенного государства, поскольку названия государств, а не регионов оформляются в русской традиции с помощью предлогов в (во) и из...» (Граудина Л. К., Ицкович В. А., Катлинская Л. П. Грамматическая правильность русской речи. М.: Наука, 2001. С. 69).

Однако литературная норма русского языка, согласно которой следует говорить и писать *на Украине*, — результат исторического развития языка на протяжении нескольких столетий. Сочетаемость предлогов *в* и *на* с определенными словами объясняется исключительно традицией.
Ср.: в школе, в институте, в аптеке, в отделе, но: на заводе, на почте, на курорте, на складе и т. д. Литературная норма не может измениться в одночасье из-за каких-либо политических процессов.
[**Как правильно: на Украине или в Украине?** | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/hot10/)

Comment: Вся штука в том, что т.н. "литературная норма" - на самом деле искуственно навязанный выбор одного из двух равновозможных (хотя и не равночастотных) вариантов.

Comment: Политика не должна влиять на  правила русского языка.

Answer (score 8):

Правильно "на Украину". Правильно так, как не режет ухо, как удобно говорить, как хорошо ложится на язык. Есть ещё одна страна из этой же серии — Куба. Мы не говорим "в Кубе" или "из Кубы". Мы говорим: "Я улетаю на Кубу, я вернусь с Кубы". Подчёркиваю: Куба — страна. Но самое смешное, что существует азербайджанский город Куба. Когда советского солдата-азербайджанца на занятиях по политической подготовке просили показать Кубу в смысле "Остров Свободы", то тот обычно искал её в Азербайджане и, что характерно, находил. Так вот с этой Кубой всё иначе: "Я приехал из Кубы, и я вернусь в Кубу". Обратите внимание: эта Куба — город, а не страна.

Правила русского языка иногда меняются. Делать это должны русские, живущие в России. Все остальные должны и обязаны принять эти правила и следовать им. Кому не нравится — пусть говорит на своём родном языке.

Comment: Вы видимо не в курсе что Куба - остров. И на Кубу - потому что на остров. Что соответствует нормам языка. А что касается того что русские живущие в России устанавливают нормы языка - ну это вообще какое то дикое невежество - разве британцы устанавливают нормы английского языка? Естественно нет. Во многих англоговорящих странах нормы и слова разные.

Comment: @JackSpektor Тогда не в Великобританию, а на Великобританию (если речь об острове). Из-за звучания норма присваивается. С английским не сравнить.  У одних языков есть центральный стандарт, у других нет. У английского нет центрально, общего, есть четыре разных стандарта. У испанского есть центральный. У русского есть законодательный стандарт в России, однако на Украине с 1993 законодательно принят другой стандарт русского языка (именно русского, дополнительно к украинскому). Насколько мне известно, другие страны СНГ стандартов языка не принимали.

Comment: ***Делать это должны русские, живущие в России. Все остальные должны и обязаны принять эти правила и следовать им***  Расскажите это же жителям США. Австралии. Новой Зеландии, Канады. Чтоб над вами посмеялись. Какое незамутненное детство в голове - "должны, обязаны!" "Пусть говорят на своем!" А-хах.. Первый канал, Киселевы и Соловьевы работают не зря. Спасибо вам за ваш коммент - очень показательный эффект. :)

Comment: @swift скажем так, если бы это было какое-то не связанное с Украиной правило, я бы конечно согласился с российским стандартом. Но в России ранее также использовали в документации "в Украине". И никого это не смущало. А потом с подачи российских националистов начали использовать "на". По понятным причинам. Конечно никто не может заставить когото говорить "на" в России, но вполне ожидаемо что человек может получит замечание за такую норму речи.

Comment: @JackSpektor Правила написания документации и норма речи - разные вещи.   Разные документы регулируют. Норма *литературной* речи наоборот была *только* "на" в течение двухсот лет, но потом добавили "в", и это касалось не только Украины, а всех аналогичных случаев. Причем Украинское правительсво  на Украине добавило "в" в стандарт чтобы синхронизировать документацию с Россией. А в разных местах говорят  по-разному. Не везде, например, народный говор имеет локативный падеж "в лесу".

Comment: @JackSpektor в этом отношении в английском еще хуже. Есть технический английский , где есть грамматические структуры, которые никогда не используются в разговорном или литературном.  Есть легализ, который использует ряд архаичных слов и выражени, ради их емкости.  Есть литературный использующий структуры, запрещенные в техническом, и есть  ряд разговорных диалектов, некторые из них  обладают свойствами английскому нне пренадлежащими. И теперь, одна важная деталь: стандартизирован только технический и легализ.

Comment: Хочется, чтобы участники данного форума не допускали ошибок в своих комментариях.

Answer (score 6):

Слух режет непривычная падежная форма, но со временем к ней привыкнут. В СМИ все чаще употребляется эта форма.

С точки зрения грамматики, возможны оба варианта, но по отношению к  государству в большей степени подходит предлог В (в Болгарии, во Франции и т.д.)

Comment: Вариант "на Украине" возник именно под влиянием украинского языка. Сейчас литературной нормой считается вариант "на Украине" и "в Украине" как допустимый в разговорной речи.

Comment: И до 93-го года тоже считался допустимым? Где, когда?!

Comment: @София, вам известен хоть один не украинский словарь русского языка, где утверждалась бы допустимость "в Украине"? На данный момент такую форму можно считать максимум диалектной.

Comment: Словари иногда на десятилетия отстают от действительного употребления слова. Сейчас более интересными были бы статистические данные по этой теме.

Answer (score 5):

Обе формы правильны. 
Я бы только предостерег от ополитизирования этого вопроса.
Лет десять-пятнадцать назад я тоже думал, что "в Украине" -  дань новой, но дурной традиции, по которой Белоруссия стала Беларусью (спеллеры до сих пор спотыкаются о "беларусов"), а Кирзгизия - Кыргызстаном (свят-свят-свят!). И "Таллинн", конечно, из того же ряда - только в меньшей степени, поскольку это не государство, а город, а тут государственный этикет не так значим.

Но с Украиной все оказалось глубже и естественней. "В Украине" без всякой привязки к её государственности употреблялось едва ли не с XVII века. В русском языке, разумеется. Наряду с вариантом "на Украину", хотя и значительно уступая последнему по частоте.
Точно так же в украинском были совершенно равноправны оба варианта. Без какой-либо "незалэженой" подоплеки.

Вопрос бесчисленное количество раз обсуждался, нет смысла повторяться.

Оба варианта правильны. 
В официальном контексте принято "в Украину", на бытовом уровне можете использовать то, что более понравится.

Вопрос обсуждался тут и в рунете бессчетное количество раз, повторять все просто не имеет смысла.
Порсмотрите по ссылкам.

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2644
[В Украине или на Украине](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40285)
[Как правильно  по-русски "Белоруссия" или "Беларусь"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/724)
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/hot10
http://www.gramota.ru/forum/veche/48207/

---

И коль пошла такая пьянка, позвольте в порядке саморекламы авторский стишок начала тысячелетия.

```
* * *

Держусь я третий день без сна,
Стакан в себя залив.
Я только что вернулся с на...
И вот - послали в...

Судьба такая мне дана,
Вся жизнь - сплошной призыв.
Пошлют меня обратно на...
Когда вернусь я из в...

Еще поллитру съев до дна,
Я вышел на карниз.
Мне цель отчетлива видна-
Теперь вперед и вниз...
Туда ведет дорога вна,
Оттуда едешь изс.

©2003
```

http://gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=1&i=7263&t=7263

Comment: >> Я бы только предостерег от ополитизирования этого вопроса.

А вот это как раз и не получается. Не знаю, как там в XVII веке, а вот в двадцатом было **исключительно** НА. И вопрос подняли именно политики, а не кто иной. Как же без ополитизирования?

Comment: В XVII веке была обратная ситуация "**в** украине" употреблялось в России. А "**на** Украине" - говорили сами украинцы.  
Дело в том, что до петровских реформ существовали "укрАинные воеводства", которые обычно и именовались "украинами". А украинцы, в силу историко-географических особенностей, именовали "УкрАиной" именно свою территорию.

Comment: >Дело в том, что до петровских реформ существовали "укрАинные воеводства"  
  
Это Марк Из, должно быть, лучше знает. Но в любом случае Украина восходит к гораздо более ранним временам. "Оукраины" русских земель зафиксированы, кажется еще в домонгольские времена. Причем (предположительно) в занчении не "окраина", а близком современному край (регион).     
    
>А вот это как раз и не получается.    
    
Ну это уж как кто понимает "политизацию" ))).   
Я-то как раз о том, что не стоит идти на поводу у политиков аргументировать употребление "В" возникшей государственностью.

Comment: Форма "В" насамом деле в перспективе предпочтительнее в официальной документации.. потому как переводится однозначно. Изза этого госстандарт ее и придерживался. Однако слух оена режет.

Answer (score 4):

То, что "на Украине" и "c Украины" является литературной нормой в России, широко известно. Известно также, что "в Украине" и "из Украины" является актом эдакой политкорректности, уступкой русскоязычным украинцам. Но давайте сравним английский в Великобритании и в США, Австралии, Индии и т.д. Мы увидим массу различий, и никто не считает себя ущемленным. Поэтому рано или поздно мы должны будем осознать, что русский язык на Украине, в Молдавии, в Белоруссии и других странах может отличаться от московской нормы и это никак не соотносится с политикой. Не надо в России "в Украине" и "из Украины", не надо Кыргызстана вместо Киргизии, Молдовы вместо Молдавии, Беларуси вместо Белоруссии и т.д.
Другое дело, что словосочетания типа "в северной Украине" звучат для нас сейчас почти так же правильно, как "на северной Украине". Но если эта тенденция начнет лет через двадцать преобладать, вот тогда и будем обсуждать смену нормы. А тогда и русский язык на Украине отойдет от московского еще на несколько шагов. Итак, — никакой политики в языке, даже если многие из нас (я в том числе) сочувствуют украинцам.

Comment: Когда русский язык на Украине станет таким, как немецкий для люксембуржцев, швейцарцев, лихтенштейцев, австрийцев - пусть и делают с ним, что получится. А пока он для государства - иностранный(хоть и родной для большинства населения) - можно поправлять и учить.

Answer (score 3):

Литературная норма – "на Украине". Почему так получилось, как говорят граждане Украины и чего требуют от нас – дело десятое. Есть литературная норма, она закреплена официально (и в словарях, и в названии профильных гос. учреждений) и популярна в народе. Всё, вопрос исчерпан.

Comment: Нет не исчерпан. Литературная норма - приставка В употребляется к государствам. На - к островам. И в официальных документах РФ употреблялось форма "В" - получается это не литературно?

Comment: @JackSpektor: тогда как объяснить «на Кубе», «в Исландии» (оба — государства) и «в Гренландии» (остров, не государство)?

Comment: @texnic На Кубе (остров), в Исландии (государство) - конечно тут есть несогласованность но оно согласно правилам. Украина НЕ остров и ТАКИ ДА государство, поэтому причина по которой не использовать предлог В не понятна.

Comment: @JackSpektor, а Гренландия (не государство, но остров, и всё же «в»)? Суть в том, что в любом языке есть исключения. В русском предлоги при слове «Украина» относятся к исключениям. И ссылаться на правила поэтому нет смысла. Относится ли ситуация к исключениям, решают лингвисты, а они пока говорят, что в данном случае — да.

Comment: @texnic Российские лингвисты? Даже в России однозначности нету по этому вопросу. А в Украине это уже устоявшееся норма.

Comment: @JackSpektor: (1) Если мы говорим о русском языке и российских его носителях, то нормы устанавливаются российскими лингвистами. Для английского и американцев, например, нормы устанавливаются американскими специалистами, а не английскими. (2) Никто никого не заставляет говорить в соответствии с нормами, и каждый сам решает, каким нормам следовать. Это может быть принято, например, на уровне редакции журнала. (3) Однозначность должна быть не в России в целом, а среди признанных нормоустанавливающих инстанции. Я о неоднозначности там не знаю.

Comment: (4) Возможно и отсутствие однозначности. В британском английском, например, есть оксфордское и кембриджское нормативное написание. Но это довольно редкое явление, связанное с нелюбовью англичан к нормированию вне технических наук вообще. В США, Германии, Франции такого не наблюдается, существует один вариант нормативного языка.

Comment: @texnic Тогда строго говоря получается что ответ на вопрос будет - в Украине на уровне прессы и государства принято следовать норме с предлогом В, а в России на аналогичном уровне следуют традиции согласно которой Украина есть исключение из нормы т.к. так сложилось исторически. Уж если говорить о правилах - то оба варианта формально не нарушают никаких норм. Согласны?

Comment: вот кстати пример мнения украинского лингвиста, профессора Лидии Стародубцевой - согласно её мнению обе нормы корректны, но предпочтительно говорить "В"

https://www.svoboda.org/a/28332799.html

Answer (score 0):

В последнее время во многих сообществах набирает популярность компромиссный вариант  **"в/на Украину"**. В онлайн-общении во многих случаях имеет смысл употреблять именно этот вариант, так как он уже сам по себе отражает способность к диалогу и готовность говорящего услышать мнение, отличное от своего.

Пример применения:

> **В/на Украине** в последние годы очень актуален анекдот:
>   - Скажите, как правильнее: "в Украину" или "на Украину"?
>   - Сейчас самое правильное и разумное - *из Украины*!