# Беларусь — беларуский

Tags: грамотная-речь, этноним

Официальное название Беларуси — Республика Беларусь, и следовательно необходимо писать «беларуский» и «беларус»; в таком случае, почему в русском языке до сих пор употребляются «рудиментарные» времён Белорусской ССР производные «белорусский» и «белорус»?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/724/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%91%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%91%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8c

Answer (score 4):

Официальное наименование "Республика Беларусь" - норма *директивная*, введённая в интересах общения между ведомствами двух государств, имеющих государственным русский язык (в других языковых случаях отличающиеся самоназвания учитываются крайне редко, напр. у нас нет слова "Дойчланд"). Вы не услышите в России слова "Беларусь" в разговоре, и оно крайне нетипично в обычных печатных публикациях, хотя узнаваемо и понятно в официальных материалах. Но даже если бы это самоназвание прижилось в варианте языка, на котором говорят в России, то прилагательное писалось бы со сдвоенной -сс- (одна буква от корня, другая - от суффикса), то есть, если пофантазировать, то вышло бы "*белару**сс**кий*". Для сравнения: Поле**сс**кий (от слова Полесье) университет в Брестской области. Слово же "беларус" (как гражданство) при таком допущении лишь сосуществовало бы с обычным "белорус", которое продолжало бы обозначать принадлежность к этносу, независимо от того, как стала бы складываться практика употребления русского языка в Белоруссии.

Answer (score 3):

Я исхожу из того, что русский и белорусский — два разных языка, каждый из них — государственный язык в своей стране и развивается по своим законам. В русском языке издавна существуют слова *Белоруссия*, *белорус*, *белорусский*. В связи с появлением нового государства, которое назвало себя на своем языке *Беларусь*, было решено называть его созвучно и по-русски: *Беларусь*. При этом все остальные слова, такие как *Белоруссия*, *белорус* и *белорусский*, никто не отменял, так как процесс изменения языка не должен управляться директивами сверху. Так, в Википедии наряду с официальным названием *Респу́блика Белару́сь* дается и неофициальное — Белоруссия.